# How to catch last iteration inside $.each in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties

```
var arr = {'a':fn1,'b':fn2,'c':fn3}

$.each(arr,function(name,func){
(do something particular for the last iteration)
...
})
```

It'll be best if no additional variables are used.

**EDIT**:
I mean **LITERALLY** last one,which is the last pair I type them.

Comment: Why so you need to know when it’s the last element? Maybe there’s a simpler solution.

Comment: Note that your `arr` is an object and object members in JavaScript do not have a guaranteed order. So there is in fact no "last" item.

Comment: @Fabian Neumann ,can you prove that?

Comment: Why does he have to prove something that's in the specifications of javascript? According to the specs, literally: *"The mechanics of enumerating the properties is implementation dependent. The order of enumeration is defined by the object."*

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert: I'd say that's the "proof" the OP was looking for - a call for citation, rather.

Comment: I don't mean the conceptually last one,but literally last one,can you guys understand?

Comment: There's no way to know that. The javascript compiler/interpreter is free to return the properties in whatever order it pleases. That's what the specs say, and there's not a lot you can do about that.

Comment: But for a fixed object,when you do $.each,the order is fixed,right?

Comment: No it's not. It's undefined, for any object, no matter how it was created.

Answer (score 33):

Your example variable is called 'arr', but it's not an array at all (it's an object). This makes it a little confusing.

When iterating over an object, there's no such thing as a "last" property, because the order of properties is undefined by design.

When iterating over an array, you can simply compare the first parameter of the callback with the (array.length-1) to detect the last iteration.

In code (for arrays):

```
var arr = [ "a","b","c" ];

$.each(arr, function(i,val) { if (i == arr.length-1) ... });
```

Comment: Would also like to know why it would have been downvoted... if there's something wrong then let us know why (otherwise how do we learn?)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you really don't answer his question. Using an extra variable outside the loop you can detect what the last key iterated over was. He wants a way to do that without the extra variable. It doesn't matter that the iteration order isn't always the same, often you just need to know the last one to decide if you want to add a comma or a period when generating text or something.

Comment: @Lance: If you read the question carefully, you'll see that the OP really wants to know what the last property is in the object: Quote: "I mean LITERALLY last one,which is the last pair I type them."

Answer (score 4):

Philippe Leybaert's answer outlines the problems with your question very well, and there is probably a clearer way of doing what you want. But that said, I cannot see a way to do what you ask without using an extra variable.

```
var obj = { 'a': fn1, 'b': fn2, 'c': fn3 };
var lastKey;

$.each(obj, function(key, fn) {
    // do stuff...
    lastKey = key;
});

obj[lastKey].doStuffForLastIteration();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need something to happen, say you are iterating over a single list and you wanted another object to be inserted conditionally but if the condition is not met you need it to be inserted last, you can do something like:

```
$list = $({{some_selector}});
$list_elt = $({{some_html}})
$list.each(function (i) {
    if ({{condition is met}}) {
         $(this).before($list_elt);
         return false;
    }
    else if (i == $list.length - 1) {
        $(this).after($list_elt);
        return false;
    }
});
```

which is the same thing as Philippe's solution, really. If there is some reason this should not work, please comment and let me know, because I use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I propose a brand new, improved answer.

An elegant way could be using a `after()` function wrapper. Here's the code:

```
function after(fn, times){
   return function(){
     if(--times === 0){
       var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
       fn.apply(this, args);
     }
   };
 }
```

`fn` is the function you want to be executed at last, `times` is the number of different response you are waiting for.

`after()` wraps your function and creates a new function that runs its code only after `times` calls. Here's an example in brief:

```
function onLastResponse(foo){
  console.log('this is last iteration');
}

var myCallback = after(onLastResponse, 3);

myCallback(); //not executed
myCallback(); //not executed
myCallback(); //executed
```

Check this jsbin for a live example: https://jsbin.com/sufaqowumo/edit?js,console

Answer (score -2):

Now that I have seen your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399226/how-to-get-the-last-pair-inside-a-object-in-javascript-closed) - where you state, "For the following,it's 'c':fn3" - it seems you might be after the value of the *maximum* property of an object.

```
var obj = { 'a': fn1, 'b': fn2, 'c': fn3 };

var maxKey;
for (var key in arr) {
    if (!(maxKey > key)) {
        maxKey = key;
    }
}

// fn will be fn3
var fn = obj[maxKey];
```

Answer (score -2):

Being `jQuery.each` function **syncronous**, do you really need to track last iteration? Just put your code after the `$.each()` call.

Comment: What if there is a Ajax call inside the `$.each` its asyncronous

Comment: @Reddy I just entered an improved answer, check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399004/how-to-catch-last-iteration-inside-each-in-jquery/33016252#33016252